# The university gave me a pay check less than my offer letter, what can I do?

Tags: united-states, funding, salary, international-students

I am a grad student at one of the University of California campuses. In my offer letter, it stated:

> Congratulations! On behalf of the Committee on Admissions and Awards
> and the Graduate Group in (Department name), I am pleased to offer you
> the following financial support for the upcoming 4 years. The funding
> will be in the form of a Graduate Student Researcher, Fellowship and
> Teaching Assistant...The
> details of your award are as follows:
>
> Summer Support with Professor X (3 months at $5000.00 per month)
> $15,000.00

I just got my first summer paycheck and the amount is only around $4000 (before tax). I sent some emails to grad coordinator, and some other parts of university but they didn't answer. I also sent an email to the professor and he answered "The pay check amount is true. Sorry, there is no more fund available for you at the moment!"

How is it possible? Can a professors behave like this? Why the offer letter of the university with the signature of the Department chairman below it, specifies some amount of money but the pay check is in different amount? How should I proceed?

Comment: This was originally closed because it was not clear whether this was a misunderstanding about how payroll works in the US, or an actual discrepancy. After OP's edit, this seems to be resolved in favor of the latter. So, I am hammering it back open.

Comment: When in the month did you start? If you started, say, a week into the month, your first paycheck could conceivably be pro-rated accordingly (with a partial paycheck in your fourth/final month for the one week you work that month to fill out your three months).

Comment: I assume that the "first summer paycheck" is for one month of work, is that correct?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: Yes, but it must be $5000 per month not $4000. They gave me a check less than the offer letter.

Comment: You're sure you are looking at the **gross pay**?  Even the "before tax" amount might still be subject to deductions for health insurance, retirement contributions, mandatory fees, etc, which could in principle amount to $1000 per paycheck.

Comment: Also, did the offer letter contain a disclaimer like "subject to availability of funds"?  They usually do.  But of course, if funding fell through, they should have informed you sooner.

Comment: @NateEldredge: As the professor confirmed the amount is true and after some emails he told me I must work harder to get more funds!! I am sure non of the options you mentioned is true and I don't know how a professor can broke his promise and it is not also important for the university to answer my emails!

Comment: Do UC university have a center that I can follow up the problem there? It seems the problem isn't important for our branch.

Comment: Was your first paycheck for a full month's of work?

Comment: You say the offer letter was signed by the department chair.  Was it accompanied by any kind of letter signed by anyone outside the academic department; in particular, was it accompanied by a letter signed by anyone in the University HR team?  On a similar note, whose signature is on the cheque?  Does that cheque appear to come from the University payroll account, or from some other account?

Comment: @DanielHatton: No I didn't sign any other papers except one paper that I confirmed my personal information like name, address, etc before the summer session starts. The cheque doesn't have any signature but the stamp of university of California is below it.

Comment: OK.  I upvoted @FrancescoLelli's answer about contacting HR, but I'm slightly concerned that you may have been recruited and paid through some unofficial back channels, and if so, that HR might have no record of the fact that you're working for the University at all.

Comment: While this doesn't have any bearing on the main point, I will say that $5000 per month sounds like a _lot_: certainly more, at the current exchange rate, than a newly-appointed Assistant Professor could expect to be paid here in the UK.

Answer (score 19):

I’m at the University of California and know a few things about how things work there. Your story is a bit too strange to be fully believable. The overwhelmingly most likely explanation is that you are not in fact getting paid less than what the offer letter said, but there is some miscommunication or misconception about what the offer letter and/or your payroll says. This may involve taxes, or some difficult to parse legalese or accounting language in the offer letter and/or the payroll printout.

A slightly less probable, but possible, explanation, is that there was a clerical error in the entry of your salary details into the system, that led to you in fact getting paid a different amount than you are supposed to. This actually happened to me when I started a postdoc (also at a UC school), and was easily corrected when I pointed it out.

The least likely explanation is that they are intentionally paying you less than they promised. In the UC system this would be essentially impossible to get away with, and would lead to quite severe consequences for anyone who was complicit, such as disciplinary action. Whatever the consequences to the people behind such a decision, I believe the university would not allow this to happen, and would move mountains to ensure that its commitment to you was honored.

Please talk to your department contacts to get this sorted out. The graduate program coordinator, graduate program chair, department vice chairs and chair, and department business manager would all be good places to start. Good luck! (And if it’s not too difficult, come back to update us on what happened… :-))

Comment: In the case of faculty salaries, a discrepancy could arise if someone appointed for 9 months expected to get 1/9 of the annual salary each month but actually got 1/12 because payments are spread out over the whole year. I'm not aware of such an arrangement for graduate student stipends, but I'm probably not aware of lots of things that happen in California.

Comment: I edited my question and added more information.

Comment: @ensan3kamel ok, that’s interesting but I can’t really advise you at that level of detail. As I said, talk to administrators at your department. They made you a promise, and they should, and hopefully will, honor it.

Comment: Couldn't a clerical error also have happened when the offer letter was drafted? I.e., they might be paying exactly what they *wanted* to offer, bit accidently ordered more.

Comment: @Maeher sure, it’s theoretically possible, but this falls under the category of “they are intentionally paying you less than they promised”, the least likely option I outlined. From OP’s perspective it should not matter whether they intended to write that amount in the offer letter. Assuming they didn’t make an obvious mistake like adding an extra zero to the salary figure, if OP used that as the basis for deciding to join this program, the promise should be honored even if it was made in error.

Comment: If the offer letter constitutes the contract that was accepted by OP, I would be very surprised if they didn't have to honor it. But it would explain why nobody seems to understand why OP is upset about the amount they're being paid.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything I would suggest to check with HR. They may simply made a mistake...

Answer (score 0):

Your letter of offer is a binding contract between you and the University. They must pay you the money you were offered for the work described.

Pursue your options inside the University, ie, Department, Personnel, Payroll, Dean's Office, etc.

If you do not get a correction from the University you can pursue legal action. You will need to consult a lawyer for that. The cost of a lawyer should be small or nonexistent since they will ask the University to pay those fees.